# How to suppress display of data.frame row numbers?

Tags: r, dataframe, row, jupyter, repr

In Jupyter/R it is convenient to display a data.frame, but default is to show row numbers.  I'd like to display a data.frame without row numbers by default - not by complicating my code with explicit row number removal or special display functions.  Perhaps there is a straight-forward way to adjust repr to do this?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: ```print.data.frame(df1, row.names = FALSE)``` Considering this and that `row.names` argument is set to `TRUE` by default, probably altering that to be `FALSE` by default should work.

Comment: @M-M How would you modify the default parameters of a base function?

Comment: @Lyngbakr ```trace("foo",edit=TRUE)``` p.s. you cannot change the defaults but you can put `!` behind `row.names` within the body of function.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a thought. Like @M-M says above, it's a matter of changing the default argument for `row.names` in `print.data.frame`. To do this, I use the [`formals`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/formals.html) function. Perhaps even put `formals(print.data.frame)$row.names <- FALSE` into your .RProfile file, so that it changes the default each time you fire up R?

```r
# Dummy data frame
df <- data.frame(a = runif(10),
                 b = runif(10))

# Peek
print(df)
#>            a           b
#> 1  0.9322050 0.008458012
#> 2  0.8428189 0.621837529
#> 3  0.5830338 0.618106646
#> 4  0.4644400 0.949952236
#> 5  0.9514314 0.721358977
#> 6  0.6922075 0.721933065
#> 7  0.5438118 0.841336910
#> 8  0.5838907 0.988468879
#> 9  0.4557117 0.083863675
#> 10 0.8592264 0.119793764

# Change default argument of print.data.frame
formals(print.data.frame)$row.names <- FALSE

# Peek
print(df)
#>          a           b
#>  0.9322050 0.008458012
#>  0.8428189 0.621837529
#>  0.5830338 0.618106646
#>  0.4644400 0.949952236
#>  0.9514314 0.721358977
#>  0.6922075 0.721933065
#>  0.5438118 0.841336910
#>  0.5838907 0.988468879
#>  0.4557117 0.083863675
#>  0.8592264 0.119793764
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: you don't need to do `print(df)`. running `df` does the same.